# Accessing static fields inside enum

Tags: java, static, enums, initialization

Generally I have learnt that `static` blocks/initializations inside a Java class get executed first during compilation. But trying to access the static field inside the `enum` gives me the error

> Cannot refer to the static enum field `ExportToReports.Animal.num` within an initializer.

Why does this error occur as the static variable must  have been initialised?

```
public enum Animal{
    cat(2), dog(3);
    int id, number;
    static int num = 5;
    Animal(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.number = Animal.num;
    }   
}
```

So does this mean that when it comes to enum static blocks doesn't get executed first??Pls explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround is to put the static field inside a static inner class:

```
enum Foo{
  RED,GREEN,BLUE;

  private final int value;
  private Foo(){
     this.value = ++ Bar.heresMyStaticField;
  }

  static class Bar{
     private static int heresMyStaticField;
  }
}
```

Whether you *should* do that is an entirely different question.

Comment: What is the '++' notation in this context? Not sure I've seen that before.

Comment: @ChrisKnight ++var: increment and then return var. as opposed to var++: return and then increment

Comment: Ah yes, its clear now.  It's a pre-increment of the static field prior to assignment.  So used to seeing it the other way around I forgot it could go prior to a variable as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Static initialization occurs when the class is loaded for the first time.  `cat` and `dog`, as enums, are treated statically for initialization purposes and are initialized first (as they are declared above `num`).  When they are initialized any references in their constructor must already be initialized.  You can make this work by declaring the `num` field final which initializes num at compile time:

```
final static int num = 5;
```

If `num` needs to change value after initialization, then you would need to move it out of the enum and to another class.